# Static resource images not appearing at runtime (are at design time)

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, resources

I have setup static resources in my WPF application as follows:

```
<Application x:Class="Demos.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="logo" UriSource="Logo.png" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I can see the images appearing at design time with the following declaration:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="302" Margin="0,-106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="458" Source="{StaticResource logo}" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

But when I run my application the images aren't appearing.  Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make **Image Properties** to **Resource** and **Copy Always** from Property Windows.
Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for replying, that didn't solve the issue.  When you say make Image Properties to content, I took that to be setting the Build Action.  Hope that's correct.  And Copy To Output Directory set to Copy always.

Comment: Ok, I spotted what I'd done wrong.  I needed to add "Resources/Logo.png" to the uri.  Silly mistake!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding "Resources" to the uri resolved this issue.